# Are there any tools that can find potential errors in C source code?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

For example, I have some code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *func(char *p) {
    p = malloc(32);
    memcpy(p, "hello", 6);
    return p;
}

int main() {
  char *s = NULL;
  char *s2 = NULL;
  s2 = func(s);
  printf("%s\n", s2);
  free(s2);
  return 1;
}
```

The code will work, but has a potential error that `s` will not point to `*p`(Suppose the programmer's intention is to allocate memory to s,). One can quickly find the error because it is very simple. But in a large project with many many codes, sometimes it is very hard to find an error like this. `gcc -Wall -Wextra` does not give warnings.

Are there any tools that can find out this kind of error?

Comment: Valgrind, GDB, etc

Comment: `s` is not used at all after calling `func`, so this is a weird example

Comment: It is not a "**potential** error that `s` will not point to `*p`". It is clear that `s` is always `NULL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think OP realizes this. It is an example of an "error" by not taking a pointer to pointer as an output parameter and having the function populate the pointer.

Comment: @TypeIA since `s` is never used, its role is unclear but `s2` seems to be doing fine.

Comment: [Clang](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) has nice static analyzer.

Comment: what about PC-Lint?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually little *wrong* with that code other than abyssmal variable names :-)

A *copy* of `s` is passed into the function as `p`, you change `p` then return it, finally assigning it to `s2`. At *no* point is `s` (or `p` or `s2`) used in a way that would cause undefined behaviour, unless the `malloc` fails, which is something you should account for:

```
p = malloc(32);
if (p != NULL) memcpy(p, "hello", 6); // why not str[n]cpy ?
```

However, in terms of tools you can use to find problems, there are many. For example, linters, compilers with good diagnostic methods, memory trackers like `valgrind`, and debuggers like `gdb`.

---

By far the most *important* tool is the wetware inside that skull of yours, *especially* with your addition of:

> Suppose the programmer's intention is to allocate memory to s.

I can think of *no* other tool that will catch the programmer's intention in that case. It's no different to figuring out the intent was to add two to a variable when the code states:

```
i++;
```